# Wordpress Custom post type permalink with a hyphen separated slug returns a 404 error

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, http-status-code-404, custom-post-type, permalinks

Ive had some post types returning 404 errors where the slug is multiple words separated by hyphens 'posttype/item-one'.

Using Custom Post Type UI.

I think this is to do with .htaccess file mine is below.

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Do I need to ' 'custom rewrite slugin custom post type settings.

Comment: Just go in permalinks and update i think it will work

Comment: Permalink settings is set to 'Post name' but doesnt work.

Comment: Can you send some url so can look into it

Comment: Just delete all code from htacess before that copy the code and download it locally ,Save  htacess  as blank and then go to permalinks and update

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212654/discussion-between-parth-shah-and-qatester19).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found that changing to a new customer post type ui slug fixed the issue. 'cat' as a slug was causing issues.